# How to find the tensor product of modules that we don't know a basis for them?

Tags: tensor, ra.rings-and-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, modules

Hi

I know how to calculate some easy tensor products like $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/(m,n)\mathbb{Z} $ or $F[X] \otimes_{F} F[Y] \cong_F F[X,Y]$ or $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C} \cong_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{R}^4$ but the reason that I can do this is that the structure of these rings is kinda well-known or they're finitely generated modules I know that continuous real functions over the interval $[0,1]$ form an $\mathbb{R}$-module, so, as a challenge for myself, I tried to find $C([0,1]) \otimes_\mathbb{R} C([0,1])$, but nothing came to my mind. So I thought I would need help and hence that's why I'm writing it here now.
I also like to know what $\mathbb{R} \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{R}$ looks like, is it algebraically the same as $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tensor product ${\mathbf R}\otimes_{\mathbf Q}{\mathbf R}$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbf R}$ as a real *vector space* since the dimensions are the same, but it's not isomorphic to $\mathbf R$ as a ring since it contains zero divisors. The tensors 
$\sqrt{2} \otimes 1$ and $1 \otimes \sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbf Q$ and square to $2(1 \otimes 1)$, so 
$(\sqrt{2} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \sqrt{2})(\sqrt{2} \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes \sqrt{2}) = 2 \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes 2 = 0$
with neither factor on the left side being 0.

Comment: Please clarify if you are interested in the structure of these tensor products as $R$-modules or as $R$-algebras (with $R$ being the ring you are tensoring over).

Comment: The statement of the question in the title is awkward: many modules don't have a basis (they're not free modules).

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I'm sorry if the title sounds awkward to you, but the title isn't supposed to mean that all modules have a basis, I do know that some modules can not have a basis, for example $\mathbb{Z_2}$ is not free as a $\mathbb{Z_6}$-module. 

I'd like to know the structure of these tensor products as R-modules.

Comment: By the way, I'm new here, I didn't know that here is filled with PhD students and professors that ask really sophisticated questions. I'm just a 2nd-year undergraduate student, for me, tensors, is the highest level of mathematics that I've ever encountered! So, please, go easy on me and explain things to me in the simplest way possible.

Comment: who are you?someone from isi?i say this because the  same question was raised in our class

Comment: No.
Anyway, do you know the answer? Because the same question was raised in your class and possibly finally they told you the answer.

Comment: @KConrad: How is ${\mathbb R}\otimes_{\mathbb Q}{\mathbb R}$ as a real vector space isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?
To start with, how is the vector space structure defined? One can multiply on the first or the second slot.
Let's say the first slot, then $\sqrt 2\otimes 1$ and $1\otimes 1$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb R$, but $1\otimes \sqrt 2$ and $1\otimes 1$ are not.
It rather seems to me that ${\mathbb R}\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb R$ has the same diemnsion over $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R$ has over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @some1.new4u: Then perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com/ is the more appropriate site for you to ask your questions. MO is for research-level questions.

Comment: To expand on Johannes' comment: at http://math.stackexchange.com/ the answers and discussion might be at a level more suitable to your background. It is a natural and worthwhile question, though.